# Drupal 7 Solr Indexing Error showing "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term"

Tags: exception, drupal, solr, indexing

In Drupal 7.14, when i Index my Whole Site, Solr is showing following error:

```
AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. 
Path: /batch?id=1938&op=do StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7539 of /project/path/includes/common.inc).
```

So when i look into the lines in `/includes/common.inc` (around lines: 7537):

```
// Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
  throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
}
```

- What is that chunk of code (in `common.inc`) is doing actually please?
- How can i overcome that error?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this module https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage it will delete all empty bundles.